# keyboardType for UITextField

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, xcode4.5

I want a `UITextField` to allow only `alphabets.SpecialCharacters(@,!,,,)` and numbers are not allowed.So thought of restricting the keyboard type to `txtfirstname.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;`

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
 txtfirstname.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
}
```

But when I press numbers then also they are getting entered in textfield.Why is it so?

When a number or special character is pressed in `txtfirstname` then it should get entered in textfield.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Here use below function...Mention what do you need the characters in NSCharacterSet..

```
-(NSString *) formatIdentificationNumber:(NSString *)string
{
    NSCharacterSet * invalidNumberSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"àáâäæãåçćčèéêëęėîïìíįłñńôöòóõœøßśšûüùúŵŷÿźžż°§¿’‘€$£¥₩\n1234567890"];
    NSString  * result  = @"";
    NSScanner * scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string];
    NSString  * scannerResult;

    [scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:nil];

    while (![scanner isAtEnd])
    {
        if([scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:invalidNumberSet intoString:&scannerResult])
        {
            result = [result stringByAppendingString:scannerResult];
        }else
        {
            if(![scanner isAtEnd])
            {
                [scanner setScanLocation:[scanner scanLocation]+1];
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
} 

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

    if(![string isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        if(textField == textfieldname)
        {
            if ([[self formatIdentificationNumber:string] isEqualToString:@""] && ![string isEqualToString:@""]) {
                return NO;
            }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
 {
     static NSCharacterSet *charSet2 = nil;
     if(!charSet2) 
  {

     charSet2 = [[NSCharacterSet  characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ./,':+_)\(*~`=&^%$#@!,-?<>\"{}][| "] invertedSet];

  } 
        NSRange location = [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:charSet2];
        return (location.location == NSNotFound);


 }
```